# Why doesn't my script run?

Tags: jquery, html

I've looked this over so many times and I can't figure out why my script is not running AT ALL. Any help would be appreciated...

The script....

```
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li#profiles').addClass('active');
        $('#content').load('profiles');

        $('nav ul li a').click(function() {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            var link = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            $('#content').load(link);
            return false;
        }); // end click
    }); // end ready
</script>

<body>
```

within the body I have this....

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="profiles"><a href="profiles">Guest Profiles</a></li>
        <li id="config"><a href="config">Configuration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have this style set to see if it is working....

```
<style>
    .active a {color : rgb(80,180,80);}
</style>
```

When loading my page, the profiles link is the typical blue. I'm using Chrome DevTools and see no changes in the DOM..... Also, when I click on either link, it follows the link instead of the .click.....

Thank you

-John

Comment: Did you include the jquery library?

Comment: When selecting by ID, just using ID is enough, try `$('#profiles')` instead of `$('li#profiles')`

Comment: Joren.... sometimes the obvious answer is the right answer! I guess after weeks of trying to figure out laravel, I forgot the basics of javascript... Thank you.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Post that as an answer

Comment: *<sarcasm>* This question has my favorite *title* *</sarcasm>*

Comment: @ManofSnow apparently no need, missing jQuery reference was the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to include the jQuery library.  The code you have works fine.  Just add this to your head.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94waL/1/) proves that your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just forgot to include your jQuery source.

Comment: It looks like same answer is given few minutes ago.